# Finding distinct elements from a sequence using IEqualityComparer<T>::Equals only

Tags: c#, linq

Here is the following issue I am trying to solve. Finding the set of distinct element from the following sequence:

```
var l = new List<double>() { 0, 0 + 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7, 1 };
```

In my case I consider that two values are equals if:

```
public class DistanceComparer : IEqualityComparer<double>
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<double> Default { get; } = new DistanceComparer();

    public bool Equals(double x, double y)
    {
        return Math.Abs(x - y) < 1e-6;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(double obj) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Is there a way for me to re-use LINQ or any other existing framework to compute the list of distinct values ?

Comment: If you implement `GetHashCode` in some way (even just `=> 0`), then you can use LINQ `l.Distinct(DistanceComparer.Default)`.

Comment: That's not a correct implementation of `IEqualityComparer`. For one, `Equals` is not transitive.  Had you implemented it correctly, passing it to `Distinct` should work.

Comment: @sweeper so I guess this answers the question :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507022/iequatablepoint3d-within-a-tolerance-how-to-implement-gethashcode/51507334#51507334

Comment: @Sweeper it seems not possible to implement it correctly for this use case.

Comment: That community bot is a bit hammery, I wonder what the rules are it uses

Comment: @TheGeneral it just means OP himself marked question as duplicate, so community bot closed it.

Comment: @Evk ahh yup thanks, you learn something new every day